# Can you take elven accuracy twice?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, combat

I was hopeful someone could tell me if you can take elven accuracy twice. The wording doesn’t oppose it from happening, but I didn’t know what people thought.

Comment: Hi Sean, wlecome to RPG StackExchange! We already have a couple of answers if you want to have a look at them, but I think it might be useful if you specify whether you are talking about taking the feat "Elven Accuracy" twice on the same character, or whether you want to take the effect on the same attack twice.

Comment: Do you have access to the PHB?  (Players Handbook)

Answer (score 9):

## No.

According the Player's Handbook, page 165:

> You can take each feat only once, unless the feat's description says otherwise.

And here is the Elven Accuracy feat:

> Prerequisite: Elf or Half-Elf
>
> The accuracy of elves is legendary, especially that of elf archers and spellcasters. You have uncanny aim with attacks that rely on precision rather than brute force. You gain the following benefits:
>
> • Increase your Dexterity, Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma score by 1, to a maximum of 20.
>
> • Whenever you have advantage on an attack roll using Dexterity, Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma, you can reroll one of the dice once.

Nothing in the feat's description says you could take it more than once.

Answer (score 6):

### You can take a feat only once.

From the rules about feats (*Player's Handbook*, page 165)

> You can take each feat only once, unless the feat's description says otherwise.

The only feat with such a clause is the Elemental Adept feat, from the same book, stating

> You can select this feat multiple times. Each time you do so, you must choose a different damage type.

The Elven Accuracy feat lacks this sentence.